# extrapolation and selection bias

Tags: sampling, bias

I have a cohort of patient data.
I have 100 Affected and 900 UnAffected

I am reassessing one of the variables for each of the patients, however I can only do so for 90 Affected and 200 UnAffected.

It's obvious that the proportions of Affected/UnAffected in my new subset is different from the original cohort. As such, if I wanted to extrapolate the subset to the same size as my original cohort of 1000 patients, what would be the best method to do so?

Comment: Have you already reassessed any patients? How many?  If this number is >0, exactly how did you select them?

Comment: The subset consists of all 100 Affected (for which I could only reassess 90). Of the 900 UnAffected, I selected 300 that closely match the Affected for three variables (e.g. age, sex) so that I could rule those out as confounding variables. Of the 300, I only had access to information to reassess 200. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: What's the study question and the goal of the analysis?. Your new mention of matching suggests that you want to compare affected to unaffected in some way. Be specific.

Comment: I'm trying to compare a specific variable before and after reassessment (e.g. old technique vs new technique). However, I can only perform the new technique on a subset of the patients.
I'm mostly interested in observing the change in the variable from reassessment but would enjoy to see if any marked difference between Affected and UnAffected too.

I wonder if I can extrapolate the subset findings to a cohort the same size as the original but not sure that's really necessary or even possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had take a random sample of unaffected subjects, it would have been possible to estimate the cohort characteristics of the  new-technique distribution (e.g. mean, median, quartiles) and, therefore similar characteristics of the new-old differences. This would have "extrapolated" to the original cohort and perhaps is what you were thinking about.

Unfortunately, your decision to implement a matching design means that the reassessed unaffected subjects are not a random sample of all unaffected.

You have quite a bit of covariate information on all subjects. There you could reweight unaffected subjects so that the reweighted distributions match those of the original 900. The techniques for doing this are known as post-stratification, raking, and calibration. For these, see Lohr, 2009.

You can also go some way to compensate for the missing reassessments with multiple imputation (MI) and reweighting techniques. See, e.g. White et al., 2012.

References:

Lohr, Sharon L. 2009. Sampling: Design and Analysis. Boston, MA: Cengage Brooks/Cole.

Seaman, Shaun R, Ian R White, Andrew J Copas, and Leah Li. 2012. Combining Multiple Imputation and Inverse-Probability Weighting. Biometrics 68, no. 1: 129-137.

Comment: I used the R package [MatchIt](http://gking.harvard.edu/matchit) to reduce confounding variables such as sex, age and cancer status in selecting my subset of unaffected individuals. If I chose at random, these variables could easily skew my results as they weigh heavily on the variable I'm reassessing.

Nonetheless, I'm going to read these articles you've suggested. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I was trying to interpret your original request to "extrapolate" .  I am not saying that doing so is a good idea for your particular problem.  Good luck!